# How to split a String using regex in Java without losing numberic

Tags: java, regex, string

This is the following string
`(R01)(R10)`

and the output should be like this:
`1`
`10`

I was using `\\)|\\(|[A-Z]` but it's doesn't work
What should I do?

Comment: Your output should be `01` and `10` right?.. Or you want us to trim leading zero(s)?

Comment: @TheLostMind, hi the output should be 1 and 10

Comment: Oh.. Then you will have to parse the "01" as a number and then set it back to the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"\\(R0*(\\d+)\\)"
```

It means that the expression:

- should be in parenthesis `"\\( \\)"`
- starts with the character R
- then followed by zero or multiple 0 `0*`.
- followed by one or more digit that you capture in a group `(\\d+)`

`0*` will consume every 0 that appears before the first digit that match. So in the case of '000', `0*` will consume the first two 0 since we need at least one digit after (which will be the last 0). There might be some backtracking involved.

For example:

```
String s = "(R0)(R10)(R001)(R000)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(R0*(\\d+)\\)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
0
10
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("([^\\d][0]|\\D)", "");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the replacement text (unescaped $ signs?)
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    // Non-existent backreference used the replacement text
}
```

### Explanation:

```
([^\d][0]|\D)

Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «([^\d][0]|\D)»
   Match this alternative «[^\d][0]»
      Match a single character that is NOT a “digit” «[^\d]»
      Match the character “0” literally «[0]»
   Or match this alternative «\D»
      Match a single character that is NOT a “digit” «\D»
```

Comment: The output of this is not what the OP expects.

Comment: I guess he missed the `0`on the output example, the regex he's using points to that.

Comment: Also.. You will have to `trim()` your `resultString`

Answer (score 0):

For the regex bit, you probably want to learn about [lookahead/lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=R)\d+
```

and then use `Integer.parseInt` on the matches.

For practising Regexes: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and many others

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
String in = "(R01)(R10)";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    Pattern.compile("(?:\\D+0*)").splitAsStream(in)
   .filter(x -> x.length()>0).toArray()
));
```

Output :  `[1, 10]`

The advantage of this construct is you can easily extend it, for example to get floats instead of strings:

```
String in = "(R01)(R10)";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    Pattern.compile("(?:\\D+)").splitAsStream(in)
    .filter(x -> x.length() > 0).map(Float::parseFloat)
    .toArray()
));
```

Output: `[1.0, 10.0]`

Comment: Since you're using java 8 you could also do `Pattern.compile("(?:\\D+0*)").splitAsStream(in).moreStreamOps(...)`

Comment: @AlexisC. Right, it's prettier, I'll update. As java7 doesn't even receive Oracle's updates anymore, I took for granted devs are all using at least Java8. I know I'm somewhat optimistic but I'm reluctant to assume bad practices...

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "(R01)(R10)";
    s = s.replaceAll(".*?(\\d+.*\\d+).*", "$1"); // replace leading/ trailing non-numeric charcaters.
    String[] arr = s.split("\\D+"); // split based on non-numeric characters
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(arr[i])); // convert to base-10 i.e, remove the leading "0"

    }
    for (String str : arr)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

O/P :

```
1 
10
```